# What would cause a non-existent PHP file to be included anyway?

Tags: php

I am getting the following error on PHP 7:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught ErrorException: Undefined variable: throw_count in C:\inetpub\***\templates\left_nav.php:42
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\***\templates\left_nav.php(42): {closure}(8, 'Undefined varia...', 'C:\\inetpub\\***...', 42, Array)
#1 C:\inetpub\***\templates\page_header.php(18): require('C:\\inetpub\\***...')
#2 C:\inetpub\***\catalog\product_list.php(232): include('C:\\inetpub\\***...')
#3 C:\inetpub\***\catalog\index.php(13): include('C:\\inetpub\\***...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\inetpub\***\templates\left_nav.php</b> on line <b>42</b><br />
```

However, `C:\inetpub\***\templates\left_nav.php` literally does not exist (I renamed the file to `bad_left_nav.php`). And even if it did exist, line 42 is `$stmt->execute($params);`. Even barring the sometimes inconsistent line counts due to entering and exiting PHP code (`?>raw output<?php`), there aren't even any references to `$throw_count` anywhere in the script (there used to be, I deleted them).

---

I know it's not pulling from some other include location:

page_header.php(18): `require(APP_DIR . '/templates/left_nav.php');`

`APP_DIR` is defined as `define('APP_DIR', dirname(__DIR__));` in `C:\inetpub\***\catalog\product_list.php`

---

What would cause PHP to include the old version of this file? Opcache is disabled.

Comment: Did you try turning it off and then on again? ;)  -- that is, restarting the server.  Either the file exists, or something in your setup is caching old code.

Comment: I would love to! ... Unfortunately, I don't have direct control of the server, and trying to contact the hosting provider to restart the server (without them screwing something else up) is... unreliable, at best. We're in the process of trying to migrate to a new host, but we still have to maintain and update the old server at the same time :(

Comment: Whatever it is, it is super pervasive... I renamed the folder "templates" to "~templates~" and called `file_get_contents(APP_DIR . '/templates/page_header.php'));` immediately before the require and got a "failed to open stream: No such file or directory" error. But renaming the folder back to "templates" doesn't throw the no such file error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, the hosting provider bundled the wincache extension with this PHP installation... I'll have to include `ini_set('wincache.fcenabled', 0); ini_set('wincache.ucenabled', 0);` at the start of every script (or in a front controller script) until I can get them to disable it, or while I'm doing the development work.

Comment: Why are you doing development work on the hosted server? Use a localhost server for that